# Android using Select by ActiveAndroid

Tags: android

i'm new in ActiveAndroid. after successfull `clean install` ActiveAndroid with Maven and add library into project i'm create new `User` class as an:

```
import com.activeandroid.Model;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Column;
import com.activeandroid.annotation.Table;

@Table(name = "User")
public class User extends Model {
    @Column(name = "username")
    public String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String password;

    public User() {
        super();
    }

    public User(String username,String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

and create new data with:

```
    User users = new User();
    users.username = "hellow";
    users.password = "world";
    users.save ();
```

how to search username or password with ActiveAndroid? this below code is simple and i'm could not development that for search any Column database fields.

```
public static Item getUsers (User user) {
    return new Select ()
            .from ( User.class )
            .where ( "username = ?", user.getId () )
            .executeSingle();
}
```

UPDATE POST:

i want to get query :

`select * from users where username = "mahdi"`

Comment: Can you explain more clearly, what do you want? Get the user from the database, which fields (username and password) satisfy some values?

Comment: @rom4ek post updated sir. use some `select` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the users with the specific name use this method:

```
public static List<User> getUsersByName (String username) {
    return new Select ()
            .from ( User.class )
            .where ( "username = ?", username)
            .execute();
}
```

If you want to get one user with the specific name, try this:

```
public static User getUserByName (String username) {
    return new Select ()
            .from ( User.class )
            .where ( "username = ?", username)
            .executeSingle();
}
```

The you can just simply use it:

```
List<User> users = User.getUsersByName("mahdi");
```

Comment: thanks sir. i dont find any good document in web for activeAndroid such as ebook or tutorials web page. can you introducing any document about this ActiveAndroid ? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it hasn't any good usage description, only wiki on the github https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki. But if you have a good knowledge how SQL is working, just use the same queries, but in the code by ActiveAndroid.

Comment: can you paste your codes based on activeAndroid for help me to how to use methods? such as User class or etc. thanks

Comment: Do you want some examples? Sorry, but I don't have enough code, I just look at the wiki, and use SQL knowledge :)